# Powershell: result hash file verification Uppercase. It's ok?

Tags: hashing

I used PowerShell with the `Get-FileHash` command to verify the hash of a virtualbox installation file and the result was that the hash string generated by powershell matches but is in uppercase.

The string of the verified file on the virtualbox webpage is the same but in lower case.

So the verification is correct and the integrity of the file is fine?

Answer (score 2):

> So the verification is correct and the integrity of the file is fine?

Yes. Hash strings are [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) numbers. Hexadecimal digits are `0-9` and `A-F`. The latter range may be `a-f`. Case doesn't matter (it's very uncommon to see mixed case though).